# How to get all first character after space in string(Mysql)?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have 1 column named `fullname` in my database. I want to take that name and get all characters after spaces and store that characters into another column.

I am getting the following output.

```
num_street_lines    fullname                             charName
'7',               'Test Testerson abc ghi hi kkk lll ', 'TTagh'
```

This output is giving characters up to 5 spaces because there are 4 IF conditions. I want to make it dynamic, so in this case the desired output will be 'TTaghkl'.

```
SELECT
    @num_street_lines := 1 + LENGTH(fullname) - LENGTH(REPLACE(fullname, ' ', '')) AS num_street_lines,
    fullname,
    CONCAT(
    SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname, ' ', 1), 1, 1),
    IF(@num_street_lines > 1, SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname, ' ', 2), ' ', -1), 1, 1), ''),
    IF(@num_street_lines > 2, SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname, ' ', 3), ' ', -1), 1, 1), ''),
    IF(@num_street_lines > 3, SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname, ' ', 4), ' ', -1), 1, 1), ''),
    IF(@num_street_lines > 4, SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname, ' ', 5), ' ', -1), 1, 1), '')
    ) as charName
FROM address;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a stored procedure to have all the words in a temp table. from there you can get them using group concat

```
DELIMITER |
DROP PROCEDURE explode |
CREATE PROCEDURE explode( pDelim VARCHAR(32), pStr TEXT)                                
BEGIN                                
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_explode;                                
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_explode (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, word VARCHAR(40));

  -- REPLACE(QUOTE("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"), " ", '\'), (\'')

  SET @sql := CONCAT('INSERT INTO temp_explode (word) VALUES (', REPLACE(QUOTE(pStr), pDelim, '\'), (\''), ')');                                
  PREPARE myStmt FROM @sql;                                
  EXECUTE myStmt;                                
END |   

DELIMITER ;


SET @str  = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"; 
SET @delim = " "; 

CALL explode(@delim,@str);
SELECT group_concat(SUBSTRING(word, 1, 1) SEPARATOR '') as charName FROM temp_explode;
```

I have a solution, but not sure if you can afford having stored procedures and temporary tables.

Comment: so how i put my source and destination table column(name) into this example?

Answer (score 1):

I just improved the solution suggested by Sameer

```
DELIMITER |
DROP PROCEDURE explode |
CREATE PROCEDURE explode()
BEGIN
 DECLARE cnt INT DEFAULT 0;
 DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
 DECLARE tblid TEXT;
 DECLARE str TEXT DEFAULT '';
 DECLARE finalstr TEXT DEFAULT '';

 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_explode;                                
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_explode (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, word VARCHAR(40));

 select count(*) from your_table into cnt;

 SET i = 0;
 WHILE i < cnt DO

    SELECT fullname FROM your_table LIMIT i, 1 INTO str;
    SELECT id FROM your_table LIMIT i, 1 INTO tblid;

    TRUNCATE temp_explode;
    SET @sql := CONCAT('INSERT INTO temp_explode (word) VALUES (', REPLACE(QUOTE(str), ' ', '\'), (\''), ')');                                
    PREPARE myStmt FROM @sql;                                
    EXECUTE myStmt; 
    SELECT group_concat(SUBSTRING(word, 1, 1) SEPARATOR '') as charName FROM temp_explode INTO finalword;

    UPDATE your_table SET charName = UPPER(finalword) WHERE id = tblid; 

    SET i = i + 1;
 END WHILE;
END |
DELIMITER ;
```

Please replace your table name where i have put `your_table` and it should work. I have tested this solution at myside.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using `REGEXP_REPLACE` here with a capture group:

```
SELECT
    num_street_lines,
    fullname,
    LEFT(REGEXP_REPLACE(fullname, '\\b([A-Za-z])[^ ]*[ ]?', '$1'), 5) AS charName
FROM address;
```

### Demo

The regex pattern used can be explained as:

```
\b         match a word boundary, e.g. a preceding space or start of the full name
([A-Za-z]) match AND capture the first letter of each word
[^ ]*[ ]?  then consume the rest of the word along with an optional trailing space
```

Then, we replace with just the captured first letters, using `LEFT` to retain only the first five.

Comment: Brilliant.. However has a small downside to this post. This works with MySQL 8, lower versions do not support  REGEXP_REPLACE

Comment: @Sameer Honestly, the OP be using an earlier version of MySQL, I would just recommend using a regex UDF (and they did exist before MySQL 8+).

Comment: @ChiranjivPrajapati Now might be a good time to upgrade to MySQL 8 or later `:-)`